# 10k tools: How to disagree with a flag?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

Being quite new to the 10k mod tools, I just discovered a question being flaggt OT 3 times (as the question's phrasing was misunderstood, IMHO). Below the question, I see two buttons:

- flag or disagree
- close question

As I feel the question is perfectly on-topic, I obviously do not want to hit the second button. The first sounds promising (flag or DISAGREE) -- but only gives me the option to FLAG, not to disagree.

So how can I "decrease the flag weight" in such cases (except for adding a comment to the question pointing out the problem)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very well hidden for some reason. The options that are shown after you hit `Flag or disagree` button also have on option that is named "Invalid flag".

Comment: Urgs. That *box* could be flagged for ambiguous phrasing: "I'm flagging this because...I disagree with the flag". Yepp, makes sense #D Thanks! I completely overlooked that...